# Converting the characters in a js filter expression to pass to a dynamically built function

Tags: javascript, escaping, character

What I'm trying to do is write a filter into a function in a new page. This doesn't work:

```
+ "var title_text_not_found = ht_title.filter(x => !ht_body_text.includes(x))"
```

The problem is the ">" which interferes with the filter closure sign (the ")" ). I've tried passing the ">" as an entity code but it gets written out literally. I can't seem to escape it with a backslash either. What am I missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you're converting a string to evaluated code like this, but if the arrow function is the problem, have you tried not using an arrow function?

`+ "var title_text_not_found = ht_title.filter(function(x) { return !ht_body_text.includes(x); })"`